# Call a method in action class from a jsp page in struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts

I have written following code to pass a variable `artpsMstId` to a javascript function and then update the record stored against that variable:

**In JSP:**

```
    <td>
     <a href="javascript:fnUpdate('<s:property value="artpsMstId" />');">testupdate</a>
    </td>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fnUpdate(id)
{
    <s:url action='updateServiceDetails'></s:url>
    document.forms[0].artpsMstId.value=id;
    document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

**In struts.xml:**

```
<action name="updateServiceDetails" class="com.stp.portal.view.SearchServicePortlet" method="updateServiceDetails">
            <result name="success">/WEB-INF/view/ServiceSubmitPage.jsp</result>         
        </action>
```

The I have defined the function `updateServiceDetails` in the `SearchServicePortlet.java`.
But the flow is not coming to the `SearchServicePortlet.java`. would really appreciate if anyone could help me...Thanks

----EDITED-----

Here is what basically I want to do

```
<s:form action="updateServiceDetails" method="POST" theme="simple" >
<tr>
    <td>
        FirstName
    </td>
    <td>
        LastName
    </td>
    <td>
        Edit
    </td>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="resultList" >
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <s:textfield name="firstName" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <s:textfield name="lastName" />
    </td>
    <td>
        Edit
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="javascript:fnUpdate('<s:property value="artpsMstId" />');">testupdate</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</s:iterator>
</s:form>
```

Above code displays a list with first names and last names with an edit option for each row. Now I want to call the function `fnUpdate()` in a javascript so that
I can edit and save each row separately. This is what I basically need to do.

Comment: I don't understand why there's a URL tag in the middle of your JS function?

Comment: Are there any form to submit?

Comment: Thanks Dave for your reply, can you please tell me how to call the method updateServiceDetails() in SearchServicePortlet.java from the JS function?

Comment: yes Alexndr, there is form to submit

Comment: Set the "action" attribute of the form? Without knowing what you're actually trying to do it's difficult to provide anything but generic advice.

Comment: please see my edited portion in the qestion. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code `document.forms[0].artpsMstId.value=id;`?

Comment: Is the form being submitted? What's on the wire? What's happening on the server side? Is devMode on? Is logging at debug?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having form over entire table, just have seperate form and on click on link in row of table, call javascript function to submit that seperate form,

Try below code,
in jsp,

```
<form name="updateServiceDetailForm">
<input type="hidden" name="artpsMstId"/>
</form>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        FirstName
    </td>
    <td>
        LastName
    </td>
    <td>
        Edit
    </td>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="resultList" >
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <s:textfield name="firstName" />
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <s:textfield name="lastName" />
    </td>
    <td>
        Edit
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <a href="javascript:fnUpdate('%{artpsMstId}');">testupdate</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

in javascript,

```
function fnUpdate(artpsMstId) {
    document.forms.updateServiceDetailForm.action = "updateServiceDetails.action";
    document.forms.updateServiceDetailForm.method = "post";
    document.forms.updateServiceDetailForm.artpsMstId.value = artpsMstId;
    document.forms.updateServiceDetailForm.submit();
}
```